# Interpreting DHARMa residuals for a glmer.nb regression using count data

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, residuals

I am modeling overdispersed count data (detection of species) in a GLMM to account for changes in the number of detections of the individual (response variable) to covid period, area (rural vs urban) and year. I modeled animal id a random effect and after running a few different models this regressions seemed like the best fit:

```
mod_6 <- glmer.nb(num_detections~year+covid_period*area+
                  (1|animal_id), data=nursesharks_3)
```

However, when I plot the `DHARMa` residuals I get a really nice Q-Q plot but strange residual plots:

[image]

I am wondering how to interpret this? I have seen that poisson/interger GLMMs often do not have good residual plots but I thought DHARMa was supposed to account for that.

Here is a subset of my data:

```
nursesharks<-structure(list(animal_id = c("A69-9001-16326", "A69-9001-18425", 
"A69-9001-18422", "A69-9001-18416", "A69-9001-18422", "A69-1602-28099", 
"A69-9001-18405", "A69-9001-18416", "A69-9001-16326", "A69-9001-16330"
), covid_period = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("before", "during", "after"), class = "factor"), 
    area = c("urban", "urban", "urban", "urban", "urban", "urban", 
    "rural", "urban", "urban", "urban"), year = c(4, 2, 1, 4, 
    1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2), num_detections = c(2L, 50L, 26L, 10L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 116L, 2L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    animal_id = c("A69-1602-28099", "A69-9001-16326", "A69-9001-16326", 
    "A69-9001-16330", "A69-9001-18405", "A69-9001-18416", "A69-9001-18416", 
    "A69-9001-18422", "A69-9001-18422", "A69-9001-18425"), covid_period = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("before", 
    "during", "after"), class = "factor"), area = c("urban", 
    "urban", "urban", "urban", "rural", "urban", "urban", "urban", 
    "urban", "urban"), .rows = structure(list(6L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 
        7L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 2L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can post the data, or a link to it? My usual approach here is to use `plotResiduals()` to plot the residuals against each of the predictor variables, to see if I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: Hi Ben, I just added a subset of my data to the question, let me know if that works for you

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think a subset will be sufficient. The problem isn't with the *structure* of the data, it's with the whole data set ...

Comment: Ahh okay. Thank you! I will move to cross validated.